# Active Admin requires a force refresh after records are updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, nginx, activeadmin

I'm using a rather vanilla implementation of Active Admin.

After the user updates a record using the Active Admin interface the changes are not reflected in the browser until the user performs a [hard refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache#Bypass_browser_cache.2C_instructions_for_various_browsers) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>).

This behavior is not observed in development or testing, but is seen in production.  I believe it's a caching issue.

Is there a way I can force the newly updated information to be shown so the user doesn't have to force refresh after every record update?

Comment: sounds strange, exactly what will appear on your screen when you save a record?

Comment: The previous record appears.  As if I hadn't made any changes.  This is why I think it's a caching issue.  After CTRL+F5, it then shows the most recent changes.

Comment: Which browser do you use? I've found Safari, for example, caches more conservatively than Chrome.

Comment: The problem is browser independent.  Chrome, Firefox, and IE all show the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem had no relation to the browser or rails cache, but was due to **server side caching from Nginx**.

Apparently, a [hard refresh](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Wikipedia%3aBypass_your_cache#Bypass_browser_cache.2C_instructions_for_various_browsers) (<kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>F5</kbd>) will some how tell Nginx to not use cache.  Nginx, under a hard refresh request, will actually request the page contents from rails and then serve up the new content, instead of the cached content.

For now I've disabled caching with Nginx to prove this theory resolved the problem, via adding to the Nginx configuration file:

```
expires off;
```

Then I restarted Nginx with:

```
service nginx restart
```

Now everything is working fine. It seems like black magic, how Nginx could know (server side) that a user requested a hard refresh.

Comment: No black magic, the caching is controlled in the page requests:
    `Cache-Control:no-cache`
    `Pragma:no-cache`